# Ex-patriated in the Netherlands, travelling to third country - health insurance?

Tags: netherlands, health-insurance

I'm expatriated from Israel/Palestine to the Netherlands. I have a 2-year residence, a BSN number, an address and some sort of local not-so-cheap health insurance with IAK (about which I can provide more details if necessary).

I am also insured in Israel, continuing to pay my premiums.

Now, I'm about to go on a week-long trip abroad - to the USA.

My questions are:

- Does the Dutch health insurance cover me, typically?
- If the answer is "it depends", how do I check?

Comment: You ought to be able to get a specific answer, which is presumably better than one for the "typical" case, by asking your insurer.  That also covers the "how do I check" part of your question.

Answer (score 3):

So, here is the answer I got from my insurer (IAK)'s customer support line. (I assume it is true for other insurers as well, typically, but don't take my word for it and ask.)

- By default, your health care coverage does not include medical care which needs to be administered out of the Netherlands.
- You can purchase a pretty cheap addendum for such coverage.
- There are two tiers of coverage w.r.t. geographical area: EU-only, or entire-world.
- A month's worth of coverage in the entire world cost something like 3.84 EUR
- You can pay extra for: Sporting activity insurance; "Cancel all my credit cards since my wallet was stolen" service, and car ride coverage abroad.

I'm not sure how good this coverage addendum actually is, since I haven't gotten the full text of the policy and it'll probably be in Dutch, but that's basically that.

Also, many (most? all?) Israeli health care providers / health insurers don't offer a similar arrangement unless you're departing to and returning from Israel.

Comment: This is extremely similar to what my German insurance does: a token amount of Euros extra for world wide coverage. In my case pretty much anything that is truly a medical emergency is covered, up to and including transport back home if necessary. Depending on the country I travel to there are direct agreements so I won't have to pay anything, or I may have to foot the bill initially and can claim my expenses back later.

Comment: @deceze: What about a non-emergency? That is, say you twist your ankle, and it hurts, but you're not sure how bad it is. Or you got a cut on some piece of metal and you're worried about infection and want to see a doctor. Those are the kind of things an isurance might, or might not, cover.

Comment: Well, things which are clearly *not* covered is something like a regular checkup or unnecessary procedures like a facelift, or generally medical tourism. I'd assume that anything where you're seriously worried for your health would be covered. *You* can't judge whether it's actually very bad or not, that's why you go to a specialist who can.